# How to define pointers to a function with template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I am trying to define pointers to function with a template parameter like this

```
typedef template<typename Options> double(*func)(double, Options);
```

Then I would have a member `func` in some other class, that I can initialize with different parameters (Options).

Do you know a work around ?

Comment: Note that there is nothing such as a pointer-to-template. Templates do not exist at runtime, only their instances.

Comment: There is no such thing as a function with a template parameter. If you use `using`, you can define this, but `func` would not be a type but a template, and it needs instantiating; for instance as `func<int>` (which is the same as `double(*)(double,int)`) or `func<std::string>`  (which is `double(*)(double,std::string)`).

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? If you want to have one member that can store functions taking different parameters then you need some form of runtime type erasure, a templated function pointer is not that

Comment: " THANKS FOR THE FIRST ROUND OF ANSWERS " ... please dont do this. The idea is that your question and answers are not only for you, but also intended to be useful for future readers. If you have a follow up question you should ask a new question. I will revert your edit, because you made an answer, which was perfectly fine before, look like it does not answer your question, thats not very nice

Answer (score 2):

You can’t mix `typedef` with templates. But you *can* use `using` which, for all intents and purposes, entire replaces `typedef`:

```
template <typename Options>
using func = double (*)(double, Options);
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this but then when I have a member func in some other class, then it needs a template parameter

error: invalid use of template-name ‘func’ without an argument list
     func _penalisationForceNorm;

Comment: @parenthesis Yes, of course it needs a template parameter. There’s no way around that.

Comment: @parenthesis Show us your usecase then, we cannot just guess. See [mcve].